# How can I add a support library to android project from command line?

Tags: android, command-line, android-support-library, buildpath

I was getting so annoyed with eclipse and how it runs for android that I recently switched to just setting up my projects from the command line (actually terminal I am using Ubuntu 14.04), and the SDK is really very easy to use this way and I find the process less vexing as a whole. One problem though. I can't figure out how to add the support libraries to the project. Of course I have copied the relevant library into the libs folder but how do I add it to the build path? For some odd reason when I looked on the Android developers site it covers this question for eclipse users but not how to do it from command line....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course I have copied the relevant library into the libs folder but how do I add it to the build path?

If you are using Ant, just having it in `libs/` adds it to your build path.

If you are using Gradle, instead of copying the library, refer to the artifact from your top-level `dependencies` closure:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

If you are building some other way, please edit your question to explain *how* you are "setting up [your] projects from the command line".